# Since all objects are created with "new" in Java, does this mean they are all created on the Heap?

Tags: java, heap-memory

The purpose of this query is to compare one aspect of Java and C++, that has to do with the "new" operator.

Now, I know that in C++ there are two ways to create objects; with or without the "new" operator. In the absence of that operator, space is not allocated in the heap region,  whereas, in its presence, space is allocated in the heap region.

What about Java? I notice that the "new" operator is used for creating every object. Even arrays are created with the "new" operator. Does it mean that in Java there is only one place for objects to exist in - that is, the heap region?

Thanks.

Comment: In general, the same name for a keyword doesn't imply similarity -- there sometimes just is.

Comment: Am I supposed to pick an answer? I didn't know.

Comment: (I removed the C++ tag and made the title more refined, even if lengthy. Now, if the question was about C# -- which still uses `new` for Value Types which can avoid "stack allocation" -- the answers would be *different* as C# is not Java just as Java is not C++.)

Comment: Also, *some* objects can be created without `new` - Strings, and Auto-boxed primitives are two counter-examples I can think of.

Comment: @pst, that is from a programmer's point of view but the String class, being immutable, returns a newly created object by internally using the "new" operator. Same goes for auto-boxing because auto-boxing does what you would otherwise do using the "new" operator and a wrapper class for the corresponding primitive.

Comment: @Affe: You got it wrong there. If you check the original Oracle documentation, it says the constructor is used along with the new operator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the new operator always allocates memory for the object on the heap. Unlike C++, objects in Java cannot be created on the stack.

Comment: The notion of the heap is implementation-specific, for the Virtual Machine Specification intentionally does not restrict storage options.

Comment: +1 Would say instead "Unlike C++, there is no way in Java to say you want an object allocated on the stack"

Comment: Happy commenting in future.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

Local primitive types, and local *references* to object types, both take up "stack" memory, as do they both when passed as parameters to methods.

All objects themselves exist in the equivalent of a "heap".

Comment: @softwarelover the storage of Java objects is intentionally left unspecified by the Virtual Machine Specification; this is taken advantage of my VMs like HotSpot that use escape analysis to instead take advantage of stack allocation for objects :-)

Comment: He's saying within any block (e.g., function body) exists some local variables. Whether they are primitives or allocated objects, they both have some presence on the stack: primitives are completely on the stack (e.g., a 4 byte `int` is 4 bytes on the stack). Allocated objects can be conveniently thought of as pointers on the stack; they take up space on the stack just like a pointer would, which is used to reference the actual object pointed to in memory (created using `new`). As @oldrinb points out, this may not be exactly what is happening, but it is effectively what is happening.

Comment: @pickypg a fun fact is that the JVM operand stack uses a 32-bit width for its stack words. `double` and `long` are stored using two words.

Answer (score 2):

All Java objects (i.e. all things with a reference) are allocated in the heap<sup>1</sup> from the perspective of the application and the application programmer<sup>2</sup>.  Java does not support explicit allocation of objects on the stack.  Object references can be stored both in heap nodes (i.e. class or instance fields) and stack frames (i.e. local variables, etc).

In fact, there are a few ways that first class Java objects can be created in Java that **don't** involve using the `new` keyword.

- The `{ ... }` array initializer syntax can be used in an array declaration without the `new` keyword.
- A String literal involves the creation of a String object (at class load time).
- The boxing conversion will (typically) create a new wrapper object without an explicit `new` or method call.
- The reflective `newInstance` and similar methods create objects without an explicit `new`.
- Under the hood, the implementation of Java serialization uses a special method in the `Unsafe` class to create objects without executing any declared constructor.
- You can also create Java objects in native code using the JNI / JNA apis.

(There is a strong argument that the last two are "not Java", but they are worth mentioning anyway.  And the String literal and auto-boxing cases involve Java code that uses `new` under the hood.)

---

<sup>1 - There can be more than one heap, though this is transparent to the application.</sup>

<sup>2 - The latest Hotspot JVMs have an experimental "escape analysis" feature that determines whether objects "escape" from the context in which they are created.  Objects that don't escape could be safely allocated on the stack.  Once again, this optimization is transparent to the application.</sup>

Comment: While this is good info, it doesn't answer the core question of "on the stack / on the heap". Add "regardless the objects are always created on the heap" and this would be the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

**In Java, all objects are dynamically allocated on Heap**. This is different from C++ where objects can be allocated memory either on Stack or on Heap. In C++, when we allocate abject using `new()`, the abject is allocated on Heap, otherwise on Stack if not global or static.

In Java, when we only declare a variable of a class type, only a reference is created (memory is not allocated for the object). To allocate memory to an object, we must use new(). So the object is always allocated memory on heap.

**Example 1:**   Give Compile Error.

```
class Test {
    void show() {
        System.out.println("Test::show() called");
    }
}     
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t; 
        t.show(); // Error here because t is not initialed
    }
```

**Example 2:**    Allocating memory using `new()` makes above program work.

```
class Test {
    void show() {
        System.out.println("Test::show() called");
    }
}      
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test(); //all objects are dynamically allocated
        t.show(); // No error 
    }
}
```